# Python List Function

Tags: python, list, function, numpy

I have a list called network which needs to be modified by the use of a function.
The list contains 100 elements, of which each is at random +1 or -1. 
This list has to be modified in a way so that every time a function runs, it modifies an element in a copy of network. 
I then need to graph these lists on a graph.

My code is as follows:

```
import math
import random
import numpy as np

#Generate network elements
network=[]
for x in range(0,100):
    network.append(random.choice([-1,1]))

#Generate Matrix
matrix=np.ones((100,100))
p=np.random.permutation(100)
matrix[p[:10]]=1
matrix[p[:10]]=-1

#Set diagonal values to zero
matrix[np.diag_indices_from(matrix)]=0

#THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT WILL BE MODIFYING AN ELEMENT, i, IN NETWORK.
def new_sum(i):
    hi=np.sum(np.dot(matrix[i][:100],network[:100]))
    if hi>0:
        hi==1
    if hi<0:
        hi==-1
    return hi

"""HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP. I NEED TO HAVE THIS FUNCTION RUN AT RANDOM 
   ON ANY ELEMENT IN NETWORK. WHEN IT RUNS, I NEED TO COPY NETWORK AS A NEW 
   LIST AND HAVE hi REPLACE THE CORRESPONDING INDEX, i, IN THE COPIED LIST. THE 
   PROBLEM IS THAT I NEED TO HAVE THIS FUNCTION RUN 300 TIMES, AND EVERYTIME 
   IT RUNS, I NEED TO COPY NETWORK AS A NEW LIST AND HAVE hi REPLACE THE 
   CORRESPONDING INDEX, i, IN THE COPIED LIST. HERE IS CODE: """

def new_function(value):
    for i in range(0,value):
        new_list=network[:]
        new_sum(i)= x
        new_list[i]=x
        return new_list

def plot_data(ax, data, xval):
    N:len(data)
    uniqdata, idx=np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
    ax.scatter(np.ones(N)*xval,np.arange(1,N+1),s=50,c=cmap[idx])

cmap = np.array([(1,0,0),(0,1,0)])
fig, ax=plt.subplots
```

I then have to graph the 300 lists that need to be created, where each list is the argument, `data`, in the function `plot_data`. How do I do this?

Comment: Please narrow down the scope of the question. When you provide code, do it to illustrate your problem, that you will solve yourself, not to enable others to do your work in your place.

Answer (score 0):

using numpy.random.random you can generate whatever array you like from different distribution :
[the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html#numpy.random.random)